# Unity3d (Failed to re-package resources.)

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build my project it won't build and I got an error. How do I fix it?

```
 CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
 C:\Users\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

 stderr[
 W/        ( 6744): Zip: missed a central dir sig (at 0)
 W/zipro   ( 6744): Error opening archive C:\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar: Iteration ended
 res\values\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen'.

 res\values-v14\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen'.

 res\values-v21\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen'.

 ]
 stdout[
 Configurations:
  (default)
  v14
  v21
  mdpi-v4
  xhdpi-v4

 Files:
   drawable\app_banner.png
     Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
   drawable\app_icon.png
     Src: (mdpi-v4) res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
   values\strings.xml
     Src: () res\values\strings.xml
   values\styles.xml
     Src: () res\values\styles.xml
     Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
     Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
   AndroidManifest.xml
     Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

 Resource Dirs:
   Type drawable
     drawable\app_banner.png
       Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
     drawable\app_icon.png
       Src: (mdpi-v4) res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
   Type values
     values\strings.xml
       Src: () res\values\strings.xml
     values\styles.xml
       Src: () res\values\styles.xml
       Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
       Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
 Including resources from package: C:\Users\Kira\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar
 applyFileOverlay for drawable
 applyFileOverlay for layout
 applyFileOverlay for anim
 applyFileOverlay for animator
 applyFileOverlay for interpolator
 applyFileOverlay for transition
 applyFileOverlay for xml
 applyFileOverlay for raw
 applyFileOverlay for color
 applyFileOverlay for menu
 applyFileOverlay for mipmap
 Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
 Processing image: res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
     (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png: 90% size of source)
     (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
     (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
     (new resource id app_icon from mdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
 ]
 exit code: 1
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, Int32 retriesOnFailure)
 UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Anyone encounter this problem? I just fully updated my sdk manager.

[image: Here's my SS of my build-tools]

Comment: anyone?........

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of similar questions : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unity3d+%28Failed+to+re-package+resources

Answer (score 0):

This happens only on API 19, `Material.Light` is not supported on 19. You could choose API 21 if API level isn't important to you.
Also let me know what you did to solve this issue.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.